# Use sitemap to redirect 301 url

Tags: php, redirect, sitemap, http-status-code-301

I have a problem, i will do a migration of a system, and some url's will change, and i wish to create a Redirect 301, to keep de data from search engines like Google and Bing.

I have a idea, there is a way that i can create a sitemap with the redirects 301?

Why i want use site maps? Because i m need to do this dinamicly, from a data base with e old url to the new url, and in this case the redirect with .htaccess não daria. My aplication is a website in PHP, so i will create the sitemap content with a php script.

There is way to do this with sitemap, or existe a better way or approach?

**More informations**

- I use PHP on this project, there is no framework or CM like WordPress;
- I m need to creat that redirects from a database, where the old and new urls are stored.
- I already have a sitemap generated dinamicly with PHP, there are the url's of news, products, etc;
- The old system is a ecommerce with Magento;

Comment: Can you tell us some details about your environment and the script you use? there may be easier methods. Do you use a framework or something on your website?

Comment: @PeshrawH.Ahmed i edit the post with more info

Comment: you can store 301 redirects in database table and get data from that

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs has a good approach. you can store the list of old urls along with the new ones. whenever someone opens the website just query for the url. If found redirect.

Comment: so there is no way to do this with sitemap?

Comment: @RuhanO.B yes. you build it from a table of 301 redirects ..

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs so u have a example of how my sitemap needs to be?

Comment: @RuhanO.B `SELECT * FROM redirects` -> `foreach ($redirects as $redirect)` .. SO doesn't code for you, it's to answer your code-queries and issues. The logic is within my last two comments this last one should be enough to go on

Comment: also you're usinig Magento - that's a framework that comes with a built-in site map ... ??!?!

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs my question is not about how query the data from database, but how should be the sitemap, as i said, there is no framework on the new sistem, so i need to create the sitemap manually, that's why  i am asking about how should be the structure of site map. more specifically, how should be the sitemap with redirect 301 to the new urls

Comment: @RuhanO.B that's literally all there is to it. Store in DB and query the DB, foreach them on a page, and you have a sitemap.. you also have Magento, an ecommerce framework using Zend (if Magento 1) and primarly Symfony (if magento 2)